# Values of $p(x)$ s.t. $\int_0^1p(x)\,dx = 1$

Tags: calculus, linear-transformations

Let $P_2$ be the space of polynomials of degree $\leq 2$.

For $T: P_2 \to \mathbb R,$ $T(p)= \int_0^1 p(x)\,dx $

I need to find all values of $p(x)$ such that $T(p)=1$. However, I am unsure how to solve the resulting equation:

$$1=\int_0^1 p(x) \, dx $$

I know that in the case of the indefinite integral, you would simply take the derivative of both sides but that does not seem like it will work (given that you get $0=p(x)$ which does not work).

What is the method for finding all polynomials that give 1 as the value of this integral?

Comment: Is $P_2$ the space of polynomials of order $2$?

Comment: I'm assuming $P_2$ is all polynomials of degree $\leq 2$?

Comment: Does the notation $P_2$ Mean anything particular? (For example the space of quadratic polynomials?)

Comment: If $p=ax^2+bx+c$ then $T(p)=\frac{a}{3}+\frac{b}{2}+c$.

Comment: $P_2$ is the space of polynomials of degree $\le 2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$. Then we have:

$$\int_0^1p(x)dx = \left[\frac{a}{3}x^3+\frac{b}{2}x^2+cx\right]_0^1 = \frac{a}{3}+\frac{b}{2}+c$$

Thus, your solution should be all $p(x)$ with $\frac{a}{3}+\frac{b}{2}+c=1$, or if you prefer integer coefficients, $2a+3b+6c=6$. That's one linear equation, so its solution set has two free variables in it. Do you know how to find it?

Comment: I believe so--you set the answer such that $c=\frac{-a}{3}+\frac{-b}{2}+1$ and then any polynomial in $P_2$ where this is true would be a solution, correct?

Comment: Yes, that works. You can pick any values at all for $a$ and $b$, and then find $c$ like you said.

Answer (score 1):

if $P_2$ are polynomials of degree at most $2$, then you can write them as $ax^2+bx+c$.

$$\int_0^1 (ax^2+bx+c) dx = 1$$

$$\frac{a}{3}+\frac{b}{2}+c=1$$

Hence these polynomials are of the form of $ax^2+bx+\left(1-\frac{a}3-\frac{b}2\right)$

Answer (score 0):

I think if we try taking polynomials 
$ax^2+bx+c$ then integrate
$\frac{ax^3}3+\frac{bx^2}2+cx+d$ then putting limits will give
$\frac{a}3+\frac{b}2+c$
And we can also take polynomials of degree $1$ and constants ...:)

Comment: Hi, I think the $d$ should not be there after you substitute the limit and take the difference.